# VB.Net with Mysql A connection attempt failed..." error arise when trying to read data from Mysql table. Insert into statement is working

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I'm new to Mysql databases. I created and connected successfully a database for the local server. But "A connection attempt failed..." error arise when trying to read data from a table. "Insert into ..." statement is working. I searched for whole web for the reason. Not success. Anyone can help, please. Thank in advance...
**Complete error description:**
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

**Relevant Code as follows:**
following function Working and Connected successfully

```
Public Function Connect() As Boolean
        Dim Status As Boolean
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=" & Server & ";Port=3306;Database=" & DBName & ";User ID=" & UID & ";Password=" & Pwd & ";CharSet=utf8;"
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                Status = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMsg = ex.Message
            Status = False
        End Try
        Return Status
    End Function
```

Following Function returns the error...

```
    Public Function getData(ByVal SQLStr As String) As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
        Dim tmpDR As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cmd.CommandText = SQLStr
            tmpDR = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Else
            MsgBox("Database not connected...", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Connection Error")
            tmpDR = Nothing
        End If
        getData = tmpDR
    End Function
```

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that your command could be timing out. How long does it take from when you call `ExecuteReader` to when the exception is thrown? How complex is the SQL code? How much data are you expecting to retrieve?

Comment: In the getData() method, where exactly are you initializing the connection?  What's the scope of your conn? Guessing it's global?  Does the sql preform as expected when you run it direct against the DB?

Comment: @ jmcilhinney, Around 36 seconds SQL code is very simple "Select LogDesc from log;" further more: "Insert into" statement works.

Comment: @ Hursey,getData is a method of my Database class. connect is another method to initialize the connection. It works and insert method also works. all these are in same class

Comment: Don't do this with database objects. Connections and commands need to be closed and disposed. Keep them local to the methods where they are used. Enclose then in `Using...End Using` blocks.

Comment: @Mary Thank you for the advice. Please can you tell me what is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of any class level database objects. Get rid of the Function Connect altogether. If you ever start to write

```
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
```

you should know you are doing it wrong.

Don't pass DataReader's around. The connection must remain open for them to function. Load a DataTable and pass that after the connection and command are disposed by the Using block.

If you intend to show a message box to the user, let exceptions bubble up to the user interface code.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Server=" & Server & ";Port=3306;Database=" & DBName & ";User ID=" & UID & ";Password=" & Pwd & ";CharSet=utf8;"

Public Function getData(ByVal SQLStr As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQLStr)
        conn.Open
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt 
End Function
```

As you can see, it only takes one simple line to create a connection. Connections are precious resources and should only be opened directly before the .Execute... and closed as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I changed the code as you mentioned. But the problem remains same. Insert Into statement works. But Select statement not works

Comment: Show exactly what the Select string looks like. Add `Debug.Print(SQLStr)` as the first line of my Function and let me know what shows up in the immediate window.

Comment: Select LogDesc from log;

Comment: And you have an Insert statement for log and that works. Yes?

Comment: Yes it works. Here I think about some error with the connection. But I can't determine. One of the post I read that, set "Use Procedure Bodies" to False. It also changed. but the result is same.

Comment: The exact same connection string works with `Insert Into log (LogDesc) Values ('Some Value');`?

Comment: Thank you once again Mary. There is an error message as "A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll " in debug window. Rest in next comment. (because of not enough space.)

Comment: System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>MyPOS.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.TimeoutException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>A connection attempt

Comment: failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond</Message><StackTrace>   at MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)

Comment: Definitely a timeout problem. But you can connect now with you Insert command. Yes?

Comment: When a connection times out it can be any number of things. Heavy network traffic, a problem on the server, if the internet is involved then a slow connection somewhere. Really can't diagnose from here. Sorry.

Comment: Yes. definitely. Insert command works. I work with local server. (XAMPP). How so ever thank you for your kind consideration.